# Jquery Mobile: Adding thumbnail to list items shifts text to underneath image

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to add thumbnails to my list items as per the example [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html).

I've followed the [instructions](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html), eg:

> To add thumbnails to the left of a list item, simply add an image
>   inside a list item as the first child element. The framework will
>   scale the image to 80 pixels square.

but the thumbnail image is appearing above my text, rather then beside it to the left.

My HTML is:

```
<li><img src="img/facebook.png"/><a id="facebook" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
```

Would anyone know the proper way of doing this?

Comment: you can lose the cordova tag.  Nothing to do with Cordova.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to include your image inside a tag.

like that...

```
<li><a id="facebook" href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png"/><h2>Facebook</h2></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only adding this here since it appears you can't format in comments. If you do "open source" on the page you mentioned, you will see the following:

```
<li><a href="index.html">
    <img src="images/album-bb.jpg" />
    <h3>Broken Bells</h3>
    <p>Broken Bells</p>
</a></li>
```

Just pointing out it helps to check source on the samples you want to emulate.